# client-side storage for a client-side-only web app?

Tags: html, google-chrome, client-side, local-storage, fileapi

I'm teaching myself web development, and am working on a small and free web-app on the Chrome web store written in HTML and JavaScript. I'm trying to keep the app entirely client-side since I don't really want to pay a monthly fee for a web hosting service at this time.  The app relies on localStorage for saving bits of text.  I urge the user to back it up with copy/paste, but this is sort of a crude workaround.

Does anyone know how I might provide an interface for file management that involves only the user's hard drive or some sort of free file transfer service? Could an embedded Java applet do this? I basically want the functionality of the File API, apparently not yet implemented in Chrome (http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/offline/whats-offline/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind--File API is implemented in Chrome.  See http://www.html5rocks.com/tutorials/file/filesystem/ for a tutorial.